# Handling Large MySql DB through some service

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql

We use MySql db at our organisation, and tables are getting large and large. 
It put heavy load on our server and take a lot of time when Query is complex and returning millions of records.

So, we decided to use some available SERVICES to handle this problem.
Please don't give solution to handle it our own.

We are free to use any service from Google, Amazon etc.

Question is basically to ask which services are available in here, and
what would be best of them.

So, that load on our server becomes less, and data start coming fast.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using [Amazon Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) instead of MySQL. Aurora is MySQL compatible so you wouldn't have to change any code or even change the database drivers you are using. It performs better than MySQL under heavy load, especially with a high number of concurrent queries.

You might also want to look into using [Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) although this would require some changes in your application. Depending on the type of data you are storing and the type of queries you are running Redshift has the potential to be orders of magnitude faster than MySQL. I say this from experience as I'm working on moving some large tables from MySQL to Redshift currently and the speed increase is incredible.

Otherwise, are you integrating caching into your system? Judicious use of data caching can really take the load off your database. I recommend Redis for caching purposes. You could use [Amazon's ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) service for that, or [RedisLabs](https://redislabs.com/) which I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud SQL FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq) should be a good start page, to get some info about this service.

The most significative features from Cloud SQL are related to it integration with other products from Google Cloud Platform like [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/), [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq) and [Data Store](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/faq), and most commons administration and maintenance tasks managed by Goggle.

Cloud SQL is an instance from MySQL on the cloud. All main common features from a MySQL instance will be available in a Cloud SQL instance like

- Standard MySQL
- MySQL wire protocol
- Integration with tools (Ex: Workbench)
- Logs (not full)
- Statements (stored procedures, triggers and views)
- InnoDB and MyISAM storage engines
- Import/export data

Features and resources from Cloud SQL that is a differential are:

- Vertical scaling (R/W, growing disk I/O, CPU and memory)
- Horizontal scaling (R, read-only replication instances)
- Database Management as a Service (Creation, Resize, Replication, Backups)
- Fast connection between App Engine and Compute Engine instances
- Accessible from anywhere
- Automatic and scheduled backups and Point-in-Time recovery
- Encrypted, outbound and inbound, traffic.
- Instances changes (disk, memory, etc) with few seconds of downtime.

There is 7 type of [tiers](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#v2-instance-pricing) (instance templates) with different resources.

Cloud SQL has 2 billing options: Package and Per Use.

- Package: Fixed price by instance (daily) type (tier)
- Per Use: Fixed price by hour of a tier usage
  (This model is rounded by hour. 1:40 hous rounds to 2:00)
- Billing for egress network traffic only (traffic in Google Cloud infrastructure will not be billed exe: through App Engine and GCE will not be charged).
- Billing of amount used, not over allocation.
- Billing for Disk I/O (Every tier has a pack of I/O operations default).
- Storage is charged by GB/h stored.
- Billing charges are calculated using US Pacific Time.

Tip: If use >= 450 hours per month, is better to use Package plan.

Anyway, Cloud SQL is recommended for small to mid-size projects (up to 500GB DB and 10s-100s QPS) and there is a limit of 100 pending connections independent of tier.

Answer (score 0):

Transporting data that is pushing a single server to its limits onto a single cloud instance will only result in slower access times.

Purchase a machine with more CPUs, more RAM, and more HDD and transfer your SQL onto that until you can effectively implement a "Big Data" solution that splits your data over multiple machines.

If your data is not split up over multiple machines, using an online "cloud" service will give you no benefit.  You must re-architect the data to take advantage of multiple machines before you will see any benefit from an AWS or GCE.

I can't tell you how many times people think that just moving their stuff from a local servers onto AWS or GCE will make it faster.  They are always disappointed when their app or data is slower because they thought AWS = speed.  But AWS = capacity, not speed.